# Get IP address in cakephp 3.2

Tags: cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.1, cakephp-3.2

Here i want to find the ip address of system,which i want to implement.
but i stucked here.
I am using cakephp version 3.2.
i have worked on it
,getting an incomplete ip ::1,while my machine ip is 155.0.0.1
Below is code

for getting ip

```html
echo $this->request->clientIp();//getting output ::1

 use Cake\Network\Request;
```

Here i have requested for client ip .
In above controller i have used   use Cake\Network\Request;
I am not very sure about it.

Please suggest me.
Where i am doing wrong.
will highly appreciate.

Comment: looks like you're getting ipv6 address. what URL are you going to ? Try use the IPV4 address  : `http://155.0.0.1/{Route}` alternatively, just disable the IPv6 connections on your local machine.

Comment: but previously in cakephp 2x version its coming fine.

Comment: Check your `DataValidation` configure option in Cakephp, it seems they defaulted to ipv6 in their later version. : http://www.dereuromark.de/tag/ipv4-ipv6/#validation